# My decimal values are concatenating instead of adding together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, decimal, addition

Hi I want to do a running total for each item I put in my list. I have calculated a value for each item computedValue = (price x quantity). But now i want to take that computedValue and add it to overallTotal and display this variable at the bottom.

My error is that if I had for example a overallTotal= 50.00 + 10.00 + 20.00

when I display @overallTotal it will display it as "50.0010.0020.00" instead of 80.00. I cannot convert to int otherwise I will lose the decimal points

This is the code for my table

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Item Description</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Quantity</th>
                        <th><i class="icon_calendar"></i> Price</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.ITEM_ORDER)
                    {
                        decimal computedValue = item.item_order_quantity * item.ITEM.item_price;
                        decimal overallTotal = 0;
                        overallTotal= 0+(overallTotal+ computedValue);
                        <tr style="background-color:white; border-style:hidden">
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEM.item_brand)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ITEM.item_description)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_order_quantity)
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">

                               R @computedValue

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group; background-color:white">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = item.OrderID }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.OrderID }) |

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.OrderID })
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>R @overallTotal</tr>
                    }


                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: And what the problem is?, do you get any error?, why it doesn't work you?

Comment: Updated it accordingly

Comment: And what language are you using?, because that is not Javascript.

Comment: I am using asp.net MVC

Comment: Shouldn't "decimal overallTotal = 0;" be moved out of the foreach loop? And the last <tr> should be too and it needs some <td>

Comment: If I do any of that it will error and say overallTotal does not exist in the current context @JBrooks

Comment: You need to declare it outside the loop (as a razor variable, not a javascript variable) - `@{ decimal overallTotal = 0M; }` and in the `foreach` loop - `overallTotal += computedValue;` But this sort of code does not belong in the view, it belongs in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the ASP documentation, I realize you need to suffix numbers with 'm' character to treat them as decimals, if not they are doubles. This should work:

```
// Before the loop
@{ decimal overallTotal = 0M; }
// for...
decimal computedValue = (decimal) item.item_order_quantity * (decimal) item.ITEM.item_price;    
overallTotal += computedValue;
// end for
```

If *item.item_order_quantity* is already a decimal, remove the casting. Same for *item.ITEM.item_price*.

Comment: If I declare the overallTotal=0m outside the loop it errors for overallTotal=overallTotal+computedValue saying the overallTotal does not exist in the current context

Comment: As others have said, you must declare it as an ASP variable. But you should know that. I didn't want to be so explicit in my answer. Anyway I've updated it.